# How to add more than one dataframe column in pandas groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written the following codes in three separate cells in my jupyter notebook and have been able to generate the output I want.  However, having this information in one dataframe will make it much easier to read.

How can I combine these separate dataframes into one so that the `member_casual` column is the index with `max_ride_length`, `avg_ride_length` and `most_active_day_of_week` columns next to it in the same dataframe?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malo is correct. I will expand a little bit because you can also name the columns when they are aggregated:

```
df.groupby('member_casual').agg(max_ride_length=('ride_length','max'), avg_ride_length=('ride_length','mean'), most_active_day_of_the_week=('day_of_week',pd.Series.mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the doc https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html

agg accepts a list a function as in the example:

```
df.groupby('A').agg(['min', 'max'])
```